# Why do I get this reference error for an undefined variable when I run this js function

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<center>

    <h1 hidden id="result">If you are traveling in <span class="input" id="countryt">(ctry)</span> and find yourself having to cross a piranha-filled river, here's how to do it <span class="input" id="adverbGroup1t">(adv1)</span>: Pirahnas are more <span class="input" id="adjectiveGroup1t">(adj1)</span> during the day, so cross the river at night. Avoid areas with netted <span class="input" id="animalt">(anml)</span> traps, piranhas may be <span class="input" id="verbGroup1t">(vrb1)</span> there looking to <span class="input" id="verbGroup2t">(vrb2)</span> you! When <span class="input" id="verbGroup3t"></span>(vrb3) the river, swim <span class="input" id="adverbGroup2t">(adv2)</span>. You don't want to wake them up and make them <span class="input" id="adjectiveGroup2t">(adj2)</span>! Whatever you do, if you have an open wound, try to find another way to get back to <span class="input" id="country2t">(ctry2)</span>. Pirahnas are attracted to fresh <span class="input" id="liquidt">(lqd)</span> and will most likely take a bite out of your <span class="input" id="bodyPartt">(bp)</span> if you <span class="input" id="verbGroup4t">(vrb4)</span> the water!</h1>


    <h1 id="headText">Fill In The Form</h1> 
    <!-- <form action="form.php" method="post"> -->
    <div id="form-elements"></div>
    <form onsubmit="submitted()" id="form">
    <p>A Country:</p>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="country2Input" id="country">
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>An Adverb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="awfully" id="awfully" name="adverbGroup1">
    <label for="awfully">awfully</label>
    <input type="radio" value="slowly" id="slowly" name="adverbGroup1">
    <label for="slowly">slowly</label>
    <input type="radio" value="clumsily" id="clumsily" name="adverbGroup1">
    <label for="clumsily">clumsily</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>An Adjective:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="amused" id="amused" name="adjectiveGroup1">
    <label for="amused">amused</label>
    <input type="radio" value="adventerous" id="adventerous" name="adjectiveGroup1">
    <label for="adventerous">adventerous</label>
    <input type="radio" value="little" id="little" name="adjectiveGroup1">
    <label for="little">little</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>An Animal:</p>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text"name="animalInput" id="animal">
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>A Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="running" value="" id="running" name="verbGroup1">
    <label for="running">running</label>
    <input type="radio" value="dancing" value="" id="dancing" name="verbGroup1">
    <label for="dancing">dancing</label>
    <input type="radio" value="thinking" value="" id="thinking" name="verbGroup1">
    <label for="thinking">thinking</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="leave" value="" id="leave" name="verbGroup2">
    <label for="leave">leave</label>
    <input type="radio" value="bend" value="" id="bend" name="verbGroup2">
    <label for="bend">bend</label>
    <input type="radio" value="watch" value="" id="watch" name="verbGroup2">
    <label for="watch">watch</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="capturing" id="capturing" name="verbGroup3">
    <label for="capturing">capturing</label>
    <input type="radio" value="drinking" id="drinking" name="verbGroup3">
    <label for="drinking">drinking</label>
    <input type="radio" value="creating" id="creating" name="verbGroup3">
    <label for="creating">creating</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Adverb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="carelessly" id="carelessly" name="adverbGroup2">
    <label for="carelessly">carelessly</label>
    <input type="radio" value="rapidly" id="rapidly" name="adverbGroup2">
    <label for="rapidly">rapidly</label>
    <input type="radio" value="greedily" id="greedily" name="adverbGroup2">
    <label for="greedily">greedily</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Adjective:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="invisible" id="invisible" name="adjectiveGroup2">
    <label for="invisible">invisible</label>
    <input type="radio" value="insane" id="insane" name="adjectiveGroup2">
    <label for="insane">insane</label>
    <input type="radio" value="confused" id="confused" name="adjectiveGroup2">
    <label for="confused">confused</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Country:</p>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="countryInput" id="country2">
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>A type of liquid:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="gasoline" id="gasoline" name="liquid">
    <label for="gasoline">gasoline</label>
    <input type="radio" value="water" id="water" name="liquid">
    <label for="water">water</label>
    <input type="radio" value="coffee" id="coffee" name="liquid">
    <label for="coffee">coffee</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Body Part:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="toes" id="toes" name="bodyPart">
    <label for="toes">toes</label>
    <input type="radio" value="fingers" id="fingers" name="bodyPart">
    <label for="fingers">fingers</label>
    <input type="radio" value="face" id="face" name="bodyPart">
    <label for="face">face</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="clean" id="clean" name="verbGroup4">
    <label for="clean">clean</label>
    <input type="radio" value="watch" id="watch2" name="verbGroup4">
    <label for="watch2">watch</label>
    <input type="radio" value="escape" id="escape" name="verbGroup4">
    <label for="escape">escape</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    </form>
    <button onclick="submitted()" id="sub" >Submit</button>
    <button hidden onclick="show()" id="show">Show result</button>
    </div>

</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS

```
function submitted() {  
    const btn = document.querySelector('#sub');  
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

        var countryvalue = document.getElementById("country").value
        console.log(countryvalue)

        //divider
        const adverbGroup1s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adverbGroup1"]');
        let adverbGroup1value;
        for (const adverbGroup1 of adverbGroup1s) {
            if (adverbGroup1.checked) {
                adverbGroup1value = adverbGroup1.value;
                console.log(adverbGroup1value)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
        const adjectiveGroup1s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adjectiveGroup1"]');
        let adjectiveGroup1value;
        for (const adjectiveGroup1 of adjectiveGroup1s) {
            if (adjectiveGroup1.checked) {
                adjectiveGroup1value = adjectiveGroup1.value;
                console.log(adjectiveGroup1value)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
        var animalvalue = document.getElementById("animal").value
        console.log(animalvalue)

        //divider
        const verbGroup1s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup1"]');
        let verbGroup1value;
        for (const verbGroup1 of verbGroup1s) {
            if (verbGroup1.checked) {
                verbGroup1value = verbGroup1.value;
                console.log(verbGroup1value)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
        const verbGroup2s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup2"]');
        let verbGroup2value;
        for (const verbGroup2 of verbGroup2s) {
            if (verbGroup2.checked) {
                verbGroup2value = verbGroup2.value;
                console.log(verbGroup2value)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
        const verbGroup3s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup3"]');
        let verbGroup3value;
        for (const verbGroup3 of verbGroup3s) {
            if (verbGroup3.checked) {
                verbGroup3value = verbGroup3.value;
                console.log(verbGroup3value)
                break;
            }
        }

         //divider
         const adverbGroup2s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adverbGroup2"]');
         let adverbGroup2value;
         for (const adverbGroup2 of adverbGroup2s) {
             if (adverbGroup2.checked) {
                adverbGroup2value = adverbGroup2.value;
                 console.log(adverbGroup2value)
                 break;
             }
         }

          //divider
          const adjectiveGroup2s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adjectiveGroup2"]');
          let adjectiveGroup2value;
          for (const adjectiveGroup2 of adjectiveGroup2s) {
              if (adjectiveGroup2.checked) {
                adjectiveGroup2value = adjectiveGroup2.value;
                  console.log(adjectiveGroup2value)
                  break;
              }
          }

          //divider
            var country2value = document.getElementById("country2").value
            console.log(country2value)
          
          //divider
          const liquids = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="liquid"]');
          let liquidvalue;
          for (const liquid of liquids) {
              if (liquid.checked) {
                liquidvalue = liquid.value;
                  console.log(liquidvalue)
                  break;
              }
          }

          //divider
          const bodyParts = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="bodyPart"]');
          let bodyPartvalue;
          for (const bodyPart of bodyParts) {
              if (bodyPart.checked) {
                bodyPartvalue = bodyPart.value;
                  console.log(bodyPartvalue)
                  break;
              }
          }

          //divider
          const verbGroup4s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup4"]');
          let verbGroup4value;
          for (const verbGroup4 of verbGroup4s) {
              if (verbGroup4.checked) {
                verbGroup4value = verbGroup4.value;
                  console.log(verbGroup4value)
                  break;
              }
          }
       
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
        document.getElementById("show").hidden = false
    });
}

function show() {
    document.getElementById("form").hidden = true
    document.getElementById("sub").hidden = true
    document.getElementById("show").hidden = true
    document.getElementById("headText").hidden = true
    document.getElementById("result").hidden = false

    document.getElementById("countryt").innerHTML = countryvalue
    document.getElementById("adverbGroup1t").innerHTML = adverbGroup1value
    document.getElementById("adjectiveGroup1t").innerHTML = adjectiveGroup1value
    document.getElementById("animalt").innerHTML = animalvalue
    document.getElementById("verbGroup1t").innerHTML = verbGroup1value
    document.getElementById("verbGroup2t").innerHTML = verbGroup2value
    document.getElementById("verbGroup3t").innerHTML = verbGroup3value
    document.getElementById("adverbGroup2t").innerHTML = adverbGroup2value
    document.getElementById("adjectiveGroup2t").innerHTML = adjectiveGroup2value
    document.getElementById("country2t").innerHTML = country2value
    document.getElementById("liquidt").innerHTML = liquidvalue
    document.getElementById("bodyPartt").innerHTML = bodyPartvalue
    document.getElementById("verbGroup4t").innerHTML = verbGroup4value

    
}
```

When I run this, I expect all of the content inside each span tag to be replaced with its correct strings which are stored in the variables which end with "value"

However, whenever I run this, I get this error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: countryvalue is not defined at show (form.js:174:53) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):110:47)"

How do I make this work as I explained earlier

Comment: The error occurs when submit is pressed twice and show result is pressed once

Comment: Your `countryvalue` is in the local scope of the `submitted()` function therefore it is undefined in the `show()` function. You should declare it globally to make it work

Comment: I have declared the variables and it no longer displays the error. However all the span tags are replaced with "undefined" even if I have selected options for every question and typed some text for every text input?

Answer (score 0):

**hi bro** 
You should put your script file at the end of the html file and make sure that the file address is correct.

```js
function submitted() {  
  const btn = document.querySelector('#sub');  
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

      var countryvalue = document.getElementById("country").value
      console.log(countryvalue)

      //divider
      const adverbGroup1s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adverbGroup1"]');
      let adverbGroup1value;
      for (const adverbGroup1 of adverbGroup1s) {
          if (adverbGroup1.checked) {
              adverbGroup1value = adverbGroup1.value;
              console.log(adverbGroup1value)
              break;
          }
      }

      //divider
      const adjectiveGroup1s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adjectiveGroup1"]');
      let adjectiveGroup1value;
      for (const adjectiveGroup1 of adjectiveGroup1s) {
          if (adjectiveGroup1.checked) {
              adjectiveGroup1value = adjectiveGroup1.value;
              console.log(adjectiveGroup1value)
              break;
          }
      }

      //divider
      var animalvalue = document.getElementById("animal").value
      console.log(animalvalue)

      //divider
      const verbGroup1s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup1"]');
      let verbGroup1value;
      for (const verbGroup1 of verbGroup1s) {
          if (verbGroup1.checked) {
              verbGroup1value = verbGroup1.value;
              console.log(verbGroup1value)
              break;
          }
      }

      //divider
      const verbGroup2s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup2"]');
      let verbGroup2value;
      for (const verbGroup2 of verbGroup2s) {
          if (verbGroup2.checked) {
              verbGroup2value = verbGroup2.value;
              console.log(verbGroup2value)
              break;
          }
      }

      //divider
      const verbGroup3s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup3"]');
      let verbGroup3value;
      for (const verbGroup3 of verbGroup3s) {
          if (verbGroup3.checked) {
              verbGroup3value = verbGroup3.value;
              console.log(verbGroup3value)
              break;
          }
      }

       //divider
       const adverbGroup2s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adverbGroup2"]');
       let adverbGroup2value;
       for (const adverbGroup2 of adverbGroup2s) {
           if (adverbGroup2.checked) {
              adverbGroup2value = adverbGroup2.value;
               console.log(adverbGroup2value)
               break;
           }
       }

        //divider
        const adjectiveGroup2s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="adjectiveGroup2"]');
        let adjectiveGroup2value;
        for (const adjectiveGroup2 of adjectiveGroup2s) {
            if (adjectiveGroup2.checked) {
              adjectiveGroup2value = adjectiveGroup2.value;
                console.log(adjectiveGroup2value)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
          var country2value = document.getElementById("country2").value
          console.log(country2value)
        
        //divider
        const liquids = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="liquid"]');
        let liquidvalue;
        for (const liquid of liquids) {
            if (liquid.checked) {
              liquidvalue = liquid.value;
                console.log(liquidvalue)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
        const bodyParts = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="bodyPart"]');
        let bodyPartvalue;
        for (const bodyPart of bodyParts) {
            if (bodyPart.checked) {
              bodyPartvalue = bodyPart.value;
                console.log(bodyPartvalue)
                break;
            }
        }

        //divider
        const verbGroup4s = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="verbGroup4"]');
        let verbGroup4value;
        for (const verbGroup4 of verbGroup4s) {
            if (verbGroup4.checked) {
              verbGroup4value = verbGroup4.value;
                console.log(verbGroup4value)
                break;
            }
        }
     
      document.getElementById("form").reset();
      document.getElementById("show").hidden = false
  });
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("form").hidden = true
  document.getElementById("sub").hidden = true
  document.getElementById("show").hidden = true
  document.getElementById("headText").hidden = true
  document.getElementById("result").hidden = false

  document.getElementById("countryt").innerHTML = countryvalue
  document.getElementById("adverbGroup1t").innerHTML = adverbGroup1value
  document.getElementById("adjectiveGroup1t").innerHTML = adjectiveGroup1value
  document.getElementById("animalt").innerHTML = animalvalue
  document.getElementById("verbGroup1t").innerHTML = verbGroup1value
  document.getElementById("verbGroup2t").innerHTML = verbGroup2value
  document.getElementById("verbGroup3t").innerHTML = verbGroup3value
  document.getElementById("adverbGroup2t").innerHTML = adverbGroup2value
  document.getElementById("adjectiveGroup2t").innerHTML = adjectiveGroup2value
  document.getElementById("country2t").innerHTML = country2value
  document.getElementById("liquidt").innerHTML = liquidvalue
  document.getElementById("bodyPartt").innerHTML = bodyPartvalue
  document.getElementById("verbGroup4t").innerHTML = verbGroup4value

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<center>

    <h1 hidden id="result">If you are traveling in <span class="input" id="countryt">(ctry)</span> and find yourself having to cross a piranha-filled river, here's how to do it <span class="input" id="adverbGroup1t">(adv1)</span>: Pirahnas are more <span class="input" id="adjectiveGroup1t">(adj1)</span> during the day, so cross the river at night. Avoid areas with netted <span class="input" id="animalt">(anml)</span> traps, piranhas may be <span class="input" id="verbGroup1t">(vrb1)</span> there looking to <span class="input" id="verbGroup2t">(vrb2)</span> you! When <span class="input" id="verbGroup3t"></span>(vrb3) the river, swim <span class="input" id="adverbGroup2t">(adv2)</span>. You don't want to wake them up and make them <span class="input" id="adjectiveGroup2t">(adj2)</span>! Whatever you do, if you have an open wound, try to find another way to get back to <span class="input" id="country2t">(ctry2)</span>. Pirahnas are attracted to fresh <span class="input" id="liquidt">(lqd)</span> and will most likely take a bite out of your <span class="input" id="bodyPartt">(bp)</span> if you <span class="input" id="verbGroup4t">(vrb4)</span> the water!</h1>


    <h1 id="headText">Fill In The Form</h1> 
    <!-- <form action="form.php" method="post"> -->
    <div id="form-elements"></div>
    <form onsubmit="submitted()" id="form">
    <p>A Country:</p>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="country2Input" id="country">
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>An Adverb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="awfully" id="awfully" name="adverbGroup1">
    <label for="awfully">awfully</label>
    <input type="radio" value="slowly" id="slowly" name="adverbGroup1">
    <label for="slowly">slowly</label>
    <input type="radio" value="clumsily" id="clumsily" name="adverbGroup1">
    <label for="clumsily">clumsily</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>An Adjective:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="amused" id="amused" name="adjectiveGroup1">
    <label for="amused">amused</label>
    <input type="radio" value="adventerous" id="adventerous" name="adjectiveGroup1">
    <label for="adventerous">adventerous</label>
    <input type="radio" value="little" id="little" name="adjectiveGroup1">
    <label for="little">little</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>An Animal:</p>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text"name="animalInput" id="animal">
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>A Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="running" value="" id="running" name="verbGroup1">
    <label for="running">running</label>
    <input type="radio" value="dancing" value="" id="dancing" name="verbGroup1">
    <label for="dancing">dancing</label>
    <input type="radio" value="thinking" value="" id="thinking" name="verbGroup1">
    <label for="thinking">thinking</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="leave" value="" id="leave" name="verbGroup2">
    <label for="leave">leave</label>
    <input type="radio" value="bend" value="" id="bend" name="verbGroup2">
    <label for="bend">bend</label>
    <input type="radio" value="watch" value="" id="watch" name="verbGroup2">
    <label for="watch">watch</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="capturing" id="capturing" name="verbGroup3">
    <label for="capturing">capturing</label>
    <input type="radio" value="drinking" id="drinking" name="verbGroup3">
    <label for="drinking">drinking</label>
    <input type="radio" value="creating" id="creating" name="verbGroup3">
    <label for="creating">creating</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Adverb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="carelessly" id="carelessly" name="adverbGroup2">
    <label for="carelessly">carelessly</label>
    <input type="radio" value="rapidly" id="rapidly" name="adverbGroup2">
    <label for="rapidly">rapidly</label>
    <input type="radio" value="greedily" id="greedily" name="adverbGroup2">
    <label for="greedily">greedily</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Adjective:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="invisible" id="invisible" name="adjectiveGroup2">
    <label for="invisible">invisible</label>
    <input type="radio" value="insane" id="insane" name="adjectiveGroup2">
    <label for="insane">insane</label>
    <input type="radio" value="confused" id="confused" name="adjectiveGroup2">
    <label for="confused">confused</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Country:</p>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="countryInput" id="country2">
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>A type of liquid:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="gasoline" id="gasoline" name="liquid">
    <label for="gasoline">gasoline</label>
    <input type="radio" value="water" id="water" name="liquid">
    <label for="water">water</label>
    <input type="radio" value="coffee" id="coffee" name="liquid">
    <label for="coffee">coffee</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Body Part:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="toes" id="toes" name="bodyPart">
    <label for="toes">toes</label>
    <input type="radio" value="fingers" id="fingers" name="bodyPart">
    <label for="fingers">fingers</label>
    <input type="radio" value="face" id="face" name="bodyPart">
    <label for="face">face</label>
    <p>=============================</p>
    <p>Another Verb:</p>
    <input type="radio" value="clean" id="clean" name="verbGroup4">
    <label for="clean">clean</label>
    <input type="radio" value="watch" id="watch2" name="verbGroup4">
    <label for="watch2">watch</label>
    <input type="radio" value="escape" id="escape" name="verbGroup4">
    <label for="escape">escape</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    </form>
    <button onclick="submitted()" id="sub" >Submit</button>
    <button hidden onclick="show()" id="show">Show result</button>
    </div>

</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

**Check the address of this file**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few recommendations:

**First**, to avoid clicking twice on `submit` button, remove an additional subscription from the `submitted` function.

So, basically you can remove these lines, from `submitted`:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#sub');  
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
```

**Second**, to avoid `countryvalue is not defined` errors you need to declare your variables out of the `submitted` function scope, so the variables are visible both in `submitte` and in `show`

For example:

```
let countryvalue;

function submitted() {  
    countryvalue = document.getElementById("country").value;
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("countryt").innerHTML = countryvalue;
}
```